# How to get/identify the specific data from the website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to scrape a website with the code below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers.update(
        {
            "referer": "https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
        }
    )
    _ = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html")
    endpoint = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/forum/app-tracker-latest-updates?limit=50&year=all").json()
    for item in endpoint["statistics"]:
        print(item)
```

I am not sure of how to get the status of the admission under the decision tracker - Real-time updates.

[image]

Comment: what are you using to scraping  &  doesn't api response include what you want

Comment: I think you have to find different enpoint for that and combine with the old one so you will get you desired output i have found out that [endpoint](https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/statuses?per-page=50) but it contains few datas so also try from your end

Comment: @gaurav I want to get the circles, ticks and cross on the extreme left of each entry. When I hover the cursor, in the above picture- it says admitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ticks, crossesand circles represent whether the applications are admitted, denied or pending for whatever reason. This info is found under `status_id`. In the sourcecode a mapping library can be found for the numbers. When we convert this to a python dict we can get the statuses and can also reconstruct the ticks etc.:

```
import requests

status_mapping = {1: { 'id':1,'class':'mainApplicationSubmitted','name':'Application Submitted' },
    3: { 'id':3,'class':'mainInterviewed','name':'interviewed' },
    4: { 'id':4,'class':'mainAdmitted','name':'admited' },
    5: { 'id':5,'class':'mainDenied','name':'denied' },
    6: { 'id':6,'class':'mainDenied','name':'denied' },
    7: { 'id':7,'class':'mainWaitListed','name':'waitlisted' },
    8: { 'id':8,'class':'mainWaitListed','name':'waitlisted' },
    9: { 'id':9,'class':'mainMatriculating','name':'matriculating' },
    10:{ 'id':10,'class':'mainWlAdmited','name':'admitted From WL' },
    11:{ 'id':11,'class':'mainResearching','name':'researching Or Writing Essays' },
    12:{ 'id':12,'class':'mainInvitedToInterview','name':'invited To Interview' },
    13:{ 'id':13,'class':'mainWithdrawn','name':'withdrawn Application '}}

with requests.Session() as connection:
    connection.headers.update(
        {
            "referer": "https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.86 YaBrowser/21.3.0.740 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36",
        }
    )
    _ = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/forum/decision-tracker.html")
    endpoint = connection.get("https://gmatclub.com/api/schools/v1/forum/app-tracker-latest-updates?limit=50&year=all").json()
    for item in endpoint["statistics"]:
        try:
            status = status_mapping[int(item['status_id'])]['name']
            if int(item['status_id']) in [4]:
                status_short = 'green'
            elif int(item['status_id']) in [5,6]:
                status_short = 'red'
            else:
                status_short = 'grey'
            print(status, status_short)
        except:
            print(f"Key {item['status_id']} is missing from status_mapping. Check the entry at {item['date']} to see what this key represents and add it to status_mapping.")
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting KeyError: 14 !? What do i do?

Comment: Apparently there is a key 14 that is not in `status_mapping` (which goes to 13). I have updated the answer so it now captures the error and prints the date of the entry so you can look it up and add the missing data to `status_mapping`.